# How to use the Cordova/Phonegap Filesystem API with Rikulo?

Tags: android, cordova, filesystems, dart, rikulo

execuse my english...
I try to write a Cross-Platform Webapp initially just for the Android platfrom. I have to write and read Files to the Filesystem of the mobile. I've already seen that the package rikulo_gap not natively supports the Filesystem API. The Fileystem API used by Rikulo is [that one](http://www.html5rocks.com/de/tutorials/file/filesystem/), which of course doesn't work on a mobile platform.

So I've seen that Rikulo's Js-Package should make my Dart-Code interoperable with my Cordova.js-File (v4.0.0), which includes the global function requestFileSystem(persistence,size,success-funct,fail-funct). Now i've tried to make my code work, but i don't get a Filesystem back - i'm getting errors...

Here's my Dart-Code:

```
import 'package:rikulo_gap/device.dart';
import 'dart:js' as js;

void main() { 
 Device.init().then((device) => onDeviceReady(device)).
 catchError((ex) => print("AN ERROR OCCURED: " + ex.toString()));
}

void onDeviceReady(device) {
 var persistent = js.context['PERSISTENT']; 
 print("Should be Constant PERSISTENT of LFS: " + persistent.toString());
 var fsName = js.context.callMethod('requestFileSystem',[persistent,0,dofs,fail]);
}

void dofs(fs) {
 print("Success");
 var myFs = js.context[fs];
 print("The Return of RequestFileSystem is a: " + myFs.toString());
}
```

LogCat says:

```
10-23 18:08:32.589: D/CordovaLog(951): file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js: Line 12111 : Should be Constant PERSISTENT of LFS: 1
10-23 18:08:32.624: D/CordovaLog(951): file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js: Line 12111 : Success
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1060 : processMessage failed: Stack: Error
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at dart.wrapException (file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:2520:15)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at JsObject.$index (file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:11549:17)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at dart.J.$index$asx (file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:19278:41)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at dofs (file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:4185:7)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at dart.Primitives_applyFunction (file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:2489:23)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at _callDartFunction (file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:11464:29)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js:11671:18
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/requestFileSystem.js:52:25
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at success (file:///android_asset/www/plugins/org.apache.cordova.file/www/fileSystems-roots.js:40:13)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951):     at Object.cordova.callbackFromNative (file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js:293:54)
10-23 18:08:32.649: D/CordovaLog(951): file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js: Line 1061 : processMessage failed: Message: S01 File1158866550 [{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"temporary","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/data\/de.htwg.myAndroid\/cache\/","filesystem":0,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"persistent","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"content","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"cdvfile:\/\/localhost\/content\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"files","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/de.htwg.myAndroid\/files\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"files-external","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/data\/de.htwg.myAndroid\/files\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"documents","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/de.htwg.myAndroid\/files\/Documents\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"sdcard","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"cache","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/data\/data\/de.htwg.myAndroid\/cache\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"cache-external","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/storage\/emulated\/0\/Android\/data\/de.htwg.myAndroid\/cache\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""},{"fullPath":"\/","filesystemName":"root","isDirectory":true,"nativeURL":"file:\/\/\/","filesystem":1,"isFile":false,"name":""}]
```

What annoys me is, that the first Exception on the Stack is a dart.wrapException, so i guess it's a general Dart<>Js Interop problem.

I followed the official cordova instruction for Building with Android and currently i'm building with the Windows CommandLine with `cordova run android`. (And yes i've installed the plugins (File, FileUtil, Device via CommandLine and they are added to the project).

So can anybody tell me:

1. Is it like i think and there is not a common way to use the cordova-Filesystem API with Rikulo/Dart?
2. If 1. is true, is there a workaround? Anybody a Idea, a loose note oder anything else which could help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Rikulo doesn’t support Cordova filesystem API yet. You can contribute one or try to use window.requestFileSystem instead.
2. The object returned to dofs is a JsObject instance, so you don’t need to use `js.context` to convert it. That is,

   ```
   var myFs = js.context[fs];
   ```

   shall be revised to

   ```
   var myFs = fs;
   ```

Answer (score 1):

omG you have been so right at Point 2... Lost two days of my life :O (Point 1 can't work because with the dart:html package the function window.requestFileSystem calls webKitRequestFileSystem, which just works in the chrome browser and LogCat tells me s.th. like "Not supporting the function webKitRequestFileSystem)

I was irritated because fs.toString just returned [Object object] so i thought it is just an empty Object and because I've signed the function just with dofs(fs) (without Type) my IDE/Dart-API didn't gave me proposals like 'callMethod()' for the JsObject... Now i changed it that way:

```
void main() {
 Device.init().then((device) => onDeviceReady(device)).catchError((ex) => print("AN ERROR OCCURED: " + ex.toString()));
}
void onDeviceReady(device) {
 var persistent = context['PERSISTENT']; 
 print("Should be Constant PERSISTENT of LFS: " + persistent.toString());
 context.callMethod('requestFileSystem',[persistent,0,dofs,fail]);
}
void dofs(JsObject fs) {
 print("Success");
 var fsroot = fs['root'];
 createFile(fsroot);
}
void createFile(JsObject fsroot) {
 var cNe = new JsObject.jsify({'create': true, 'exclusive': false});
 fsroot.callMethod('getFile', ["DartCreatedFile.txt",cNe,gotFileEntry,fail]);
}
void gotFileEntry(JsObject fileEntry) {
 print(fileEntry['fullPath']);
}
```

And Logcat successfully tells me:

```
10-24 14:17:03.945: D/CordovaLog(6685): file:///android_asset/www/fileSystemApi.js: Line 8 : Device is Ready!!!
10-24 14:17:04.055: D/CordovaLog(6685): file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js: Line 12294 : Should be Constant PERSISTENT of LFS: 1
10-24 14:17:04.085: D/CordovaLog(6685): file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js: Line 12294 : Success
10-24 14:17:04.105: D/CordovaLog(6685): file:///android_asset/www/adam.dart.js: Line 12294 : //DartCreatedFile.txt
```